# Twitter bootstrap tooltip and Angular.js binding

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I have a link with an image that users can click to logout, 
I would love to show a tooltip when a user hovers over the image. 
Basicly pretty easy with Twitter Bootstrap, but the tricky part is the following: 
The user has a button to change it's language and when he/she does the tooltip should be translated, I use Angular.translate for this and it works great but when I bind the options for the tooltip it doesn't pick up the filter.

code:

```
<a id="logout_link" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" data-original-title="{{ 'LOGOUT' | translate }}" data-placement="left">
    <img src="img/icons/logout.png" alt="logout" data-ng-click="logout()"/>
 </a>
```

Anyone knows how to make it dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [angular-ui bootstrap project tooltip](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip)

You will be able to bind the tooltip to a ng-model like this:

```
Dynamic Tooltip: <a href="">{{dynamicTooltipText | translate}}</a>
```

And apply the translate filter. Then in your controller:

```
var TooltipDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.dynamicTooltipText = "LOGOUT";
};
```